# Function argument instead of direct ref

Tags: javascript

I feel weird about this question.
Somehow I feel the answer should be quite obvious. Yet it isn't.

In Java Script, considering that inside  another object's scope I can directly access a variable in any surrounding scope and mutate the crap out of it. Why would I choose to pass those variable as arguments to a function instead of referencing directly? What's the best practice? When would one choose to pass something as arguments instead of using the direct reference method? Is it just a matter of if I want a reference to the actual var or just its value, analogous to the kind of system employed in the C-family of languages?

For example:

Why would I do this:

```
var foo= 1;
var bar = function(foo) {
    return foo + 2;
}
```

Instead of:

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = function() {
    return foo + 2;
}
```

This makes a bit sense:

```
var bar = function(foo) {
    return foo + 2;
}
foo = bar(42);  // foo = 44
```

Comment: well your first one and last one, foo inside is not the same as the foo outside....

Comment: Functions that don't reference closure variables are "pure" functions, and they can be moved wherever you want; they aren't tied to their specific location. This can help when your code starts to bloat and you need to organize.

Answer (score 0):

> I can directly access a variable in any surrounding scope and mutate the crap out of it.

Yes, and that's one of the things one wants to protect against.

> Why would I choose to pass those variable as arguments to a function instead of referencing directly?

Reusability, basically. By passing the value explicitly, one can a) also pass other values than that of the variable in scope b) easily refactor the code by putting the function declaration in a different scope, without having to rewrite it.

Also, dependency injection: even when you expect the variable to be a constant that you want to reference, making it a parameter allows injecting mocks etc.

> What's the best practice?

To choose wisely :-) The above advantages of putting everything in parameters are met by the disadvantage of having everything in parameters - long parameter lists and having to pass everything around have quite some overhead. So when you don't absolutely need to reuse the function, and don't need to inject any other values (e.g. in case of a given constant), there's no reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The use depends on the type of problem you want to solve

The global range variables are dealt with when the value can be reused in other operations

```
let Person = (() => {

    let Person = function() {
        this.name = null;
    }
    /**
     *  You can also occupy private variables so that you
     *  can not access them externally to your logic
     */
    let privateVariable = null;

    Person.prototype = {
        setName: (name) => {
            this.name = name;
        }, getName: () => {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    return Person;
})();

// Use:
person = new Person();
person.setName('Alan');
console.log(person.getName()); // log: Alan
```

On the other hand there are when you occupy variables of local scope
The local range variables are dealt with when you will not occupy that value in subsequent operations. It is a very common use in libraries

```
 let Library = (() => {
      /*
       *  When dealing with this type of programming all the logic
       *  of your program falls into the functions but when
       *  you use an anonymous function like this
       *  you can define variables to support you
       *
       **/
      let CONSTANT = 2;

      return {
          operation1: (param1) => {
               return param1 * 2;
          },
          operation2: (param1) => {
               return param1 * CONSTANT;
          }
      }
 })();

// Use:
let result = Library.operation1(42);
console.log(result); // 84
```

I hope this works for you, regards

Comment: The first example is confusing as it doesn't use `privateVariable` anywhere